# My Laravel stopped working after I cut and repaste css and view file

Tags: laravel-5.1, autoload

My Laravel 5.1 suddenly stop working after cut and re-paste the css and views folder, it displays this error

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public\index.php on line 22
```

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public\index.php on line 22

Comment: Can you paste the code showing how you have referenced the CSS file in your view?

Comment: <link href="{{ asset('css/site.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: And all of these CSS files exist inside public/css?

Comment: everything was worjing fine, i just cut css and js folder in the public and later paste back,that is the begining of the problem thank you

Comment: can you try run these commands `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: i tried but same error failed opening required c:// stuff

Comment: Are the permissions OK to allow access to the files?

Comment: everything was working fine till when i cut some views and public/css folder,but pasted exactly those file again

Comment: perhaps you should check this `C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public/../bootstrap/autoload.php` first. also, does you `php.exe` in your environment path?

Comment: i made no changes to this C:\xampp\htdocs\yssb\public/../bootstrap/autoload.php  and i have check php.exe exit ,i made no changes to these files as app was run with no problem, i almost finish dev thank you

Comment: @Babagana Did you move your `public` folder's content or any other files/folders?

Comment: i removed css and js folder,but i backup the folders, i later replace them back that the begining of the problem

Comment: @Babagana The error seems like `public\index.php` can't find the `bootstrap\app.php` & `bootstrap\autoload.php` in it's expected location. Check your files and folder and look inside `public\index.php` check the path mentioned for both file.